# webpack building node_module import 'module' doesn't work import 'module/index.js' does

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to move code that I reuse over and over again into separate "node_modules", hosted on github (because I don't want to pay for private npm repositories).  I use webpack with babel to transpile my javascript.

So, I moved `TheFile.js` to a new git repository, and added `my_user_name/TheFileModule` to my `package.json` file, so it installs as a node module directly from github.

Now, in my code I replace:

`import '../original/path/to/my/local/file/TheFile.js'`

with:
`import 'TheFileModule'`

and have `TheFile.js` set as the `main` value in `TheFileModule`'s package.json

If I try to build this with webpack, I get a `import keyword not found` error indicating webpack is not transpiling `TheFileModule`.

However if I use:

`import 'TheFileModule/TheFile.js'`

Everything transpiles fine.

Here's the pertinent section of my `webpack.config`:

```
    module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
      include: [
        /LocalDirectoryWhereAllMyCodeLives/,
        /TheFileModule/
      ]
    },
    {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},

  ],
```

Comment: How do you call the "TheFile.js", via Ajax from the new git repo?

Comment: No I add `TheFileModule` to my package.json using this syntax https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository